# Where do I initialize my Firebase instance in my Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a Firebase database and a small Node.js application, in which I initialize my instance with the following code:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('../database/mydatabase.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com'
});
```

Where exactly do I put this code? I assumed in every file I used a connection to the database, but it said I only have to initialize it once. Do I put it in my app.js? Sorry if this is a stupid question, it was just unclear from every tutorial I could find.

Comment: I think I just figured it out, I can just register it in any .js file that uses Firebase, then just use it throughout the app. I am I correct in this thinking?

Comment: Create a database folder in root and create a file in it named config.js. define configurations there and require the package in app.js. That way you can use it anywhere since app.js is main file of node application.

Comment: @Himanshu Thanks for the tip, will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to put this anywhere in the application, as long as it is run before you attempt to use the `admin` client. Once `initializeApp` has been called, any other file that is imported and `require`s `firebase-admin` itself will also be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

I appears to be best practice to put

```
var config = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com'
}
```

and then below that, pass the config object to the `initializeApp(config);`